# Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders

Tags: angular, angular5

I am using Angular 5. Here is the code:

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient, private configService: ConfigService) 
{
...
}

login(userName, password) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http
      .post(
      this.baseUrl + '/auth/login',
      JSON.stringify({ userName, password }), { headers }
      )
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(res => {
        localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.auth_token);
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this._authNavStatusSource.next(true);
        return true;
      })
  .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

And this code results in an error:  error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: Headers; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
      Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.
        Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.

I found a related issue on github and an explanation to it: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586#issuecomment-323216764

So, I changed my code not to use the Headers type:

```
login(userName, password) {
const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };

return this.http
  .post(
  this.baseUrl + '/auth/login',
  JSON.stringify({ userName, password }), { headers }
  )
  .map(res => res.json())
  .map(res => {
    localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.auth_token);
    this.loggedIn = true;
    this._authNavStatusSource.next(true);
    return true;
  })
  .catch(this.handleError);
 }
```

And the error I've mentioned disappeared. But then in the line

```
.map(res => res.json())
```

I got the error:  Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'. After that I found that there is no need to .map(res => res.json()) with the HttpClient. But if I delete this line then in

```
.map(res => {
    localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.auth_token);
```

I cannot reach the auth_token property (Property 'auth_token' does not exist on type 'Object').
So how can I fix this situation?

Comment: If you want to use the Angular `HttpClient`, you should [read](https://angular.io/guide/http) about it, and use it properly. `Headers` has been replaced with `HttpHeaders`, and *much* more has changed. `.json()` calls are no longer needed.

Comment: Can you for example output that `res` object to console so you can be sure that it has property `auth_token`?

Comment: @R.Richards yes, sorry, I've imported the HttpHeaders but forgot to use them. But even when I use them the problem remains. And as I've mentioned, I removed the .json() call and then the problem of getting the property of the result occured.

Comment: You need to use new way. Use httpHeaders and pass options to your http method. Example: const options = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            })}